# Use the logger in grails 2.3.4

Tags: grails, logging, grails-2.0

I want to log all info levels in my app. For this I have added to the predefined:

```
log4j = {

    error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',        // controllers
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',          // GSP
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',       // layouts
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping',        // URL mapping
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons',            // core / classloading
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',            // plugins
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',      // hibernate integration
            'org.springframework',
            'org.hibernate',
            'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'

    info    'grails.app'        //this is what I have added.
}
```

In my class I have defined my logger with:

`private static final log = LogFactory.getLog(this)`

and I am loggin with `log.info("enter register method")`

However, I get nothing on the console output.(the class is called!!!) Any recommendations? I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 info    'grails.app'
```

sets the info logging level for all classes that are in grails-app folder - like controllers, services, domain classes, taglibs etc.

If you want to set the info level for ALL classes, even third-party dependencies, you should set the root logger to this level:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Level    

...

log4j = {  
   root ->        
     // root logger config
     root.setLevel(Level.INFO)
}
```